# How to implement the CrossPushNotification plugin in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have implemented the `IPushNotificationListener`, in my `CrossPushNotificationListener` class. As suggested in the [README](https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification) file.

```
public class CrossPushNotificationListener : IPushNotificationListener
{
    void IPushNotificationListener.OnError(string message, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("error", message, "ok");
    }

    void IPushNotificationListener.OnMessage(JObject values, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("message", values.ToString(), "ok");
    }

    void IPushNotificationListener.OnRegistered(string token, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("token", token, "ok");
    }

    void IPushNotificationListener.OnUnregistered(DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("unregistered", "", "ok");
    }

    bool IPushNotificationListener.ShouldShowNotification()
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("should show notification", "", "ok");
        return true;
    }
}
```

In iOS’s AppDelegate, I then initialize the CrossPushNotification plugin.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();

    CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener>();

    LoadApplication(new Origination.App ());
    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

I have also extended the AppDelegate with the appropriate overrides as shown in the `PushNotificationApplicationDelegate.txt.pp` file:

```
public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
{
    if (CrossPushNotification.Current is IPushNotificationHandler)
    {
        ((IPushNotificationHandler)CrossPushNotification.Current).OnErrorReceived(error);
    }
}

public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    if (CrossPushNotification.Current is IPushNotificationHandler)
    {
        ((IPushNotificationHandler)CrossPushNotification.Current).OnRegisteredSuccess(deviceToken);
    }
}


public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
    if (CrossPushNotification.Current is IPushNotificationHandler)
    {
        ((IPushNotificationHandler)CrossPushNotification.Current).OnMessageReceived(userInfo);
    }
}


public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
{
    if (CrossPushNotification.Current is IPushNotificationHandler)
    {
        ((IPushNotificationHandler)CrossPushNotification.Current).OnMessageReceived(userInfo);
    }
}
```

Afterwards, in my shared code, after the user registered/logged in the App and enter it's home screen, I call:

```
CrossPushNotification.Current.Register();
```

I know this method is being executed, as I get an alert requesting permissions. But none of the methods from the `IPushNotificationListener` interface implemented in the `CrossPushNotificationListener` are called.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: What service are you using for the push notification delivery? You should first check that the device has registered correctly and the push notification are delivered to the Apple Push Notification service.

Comment: The methods from the CrossPushNotificationListener are never called, so I'm not getting the device token. Neither are the methods from the AppDelegate. The register happens, as I get the request for permissions alert. This bit is confusing me even more...

Answer (score 1):

Custom implementation with a DependencyService. This code is based on the solution provided by the [Xam.Plugin.PushNotification](https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification) plugin.

**Shared Project**

**Interfaces**

```
public interface INotificationListener
{
    void OnRegister(string deviceToken);
    void OnMessage(JObject values);
}

public interface INotificationService
{
    string Token { get; }
    void Register();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class NotificationListener : INotificationListener
{
    public void OnMessage(JObject values)
    {
        // TOOD: - Handle incoming notifications
    }

    public async void OnRegister(string deviceToken)
    {
        // TODO: - Register the devices token in the server
    }
}

public class NotificationManager
{

    private static NotificationManager _current = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Shared instance of the Notification Manager
    /// </summary>
    public static NotificationManager Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_current == null)
            {
                _current = new NotificationManager();
            }
            return _current;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The member responsible for handling notifications
    /// </summary>
    public static INotificationListener Listener { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the Notification Manager with an instance of the specified handler in type T
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public static void Initialize<T>() where T: INotificationListener, new()
    {
        Listener = new T();
    }

}
```

Call this whenever it's appropriate to ask the user for permissions

```
DependencyService.Get<INotificationService>().Register();
```

**IOS Project**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof (NotificationService))]
namespace App.iOS.Notifications
{
    public class NotificationService : INotificationService
    {

        public string Token
        {
            get
            {
                return NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(NotificationKeys.TokenKey);
            }

        }

        public void Register()
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            {
                UIUserNotificationType notificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(notificationTypes, new NSSet());
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            }
            else
            {
                UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**App Delegate**

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    LoadApplication(new Origination.App ());
    NotificationManager.Initialize<NotificationListener>();
    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}

public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    // Get current device token
    var DeviceToken = deviceToken.Description;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceToken))
    {
        DeviceToken = DeviceToken.Trim('<').Trim('>').Replace(" ", "");
    }

    // Get previous device token
    var oldDeviceToken = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(NotificationKeys.TokenKey);

    // Has the token changed?
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldDeviceToken) || !oldDeviceToken.Equals(DeviceToken))
    {
        NotificationManager.Listener.OnRegister(DeviceToken);
    }

    // Save new device token 
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(DeviceToken, NotificationKeys.TokenKey);
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();

}

public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
    HandleNotification(userInfo);
}

public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
{
    HandleNotification(userInfo);
}

#region Handle Notification

private static string DictionaryToJson(NSDictionary dictionary)
{
    NSError error;
    var json = NSJsonSerialization.Serialize(dictionary, NSJsonWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, out error);
    return json.ToString(NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
}

public void HandleNotification(NSDictionary userInfo)
{
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var json = DictionaryToJson(userInfo);
    JObject values = JObject.Parse(json);

    var keyAps = new NSString("aps");

    if (userInfo.ContainsKey(keyAps))
    {
        NSDictionary aps = userInfo.ValueForKey(keyAps) as NSDictionary;

        if (aps != null)
        {
            foreach (var apsKey in aps)
            {
                parameters.Add(apsKey.Key.ToString(), apsKey.Value);
                JToken temp;
                if (!values.TryGetValue(apsKey.Key.ToString(), out temp))
                    values.Add(apsKey.Key.ToString(), apsKey.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    NotificationManager.Listener.OnMessage(values);
}

#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you must try call:

```
CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener>();
```

after

```
LoadApplication(new Origination.App ());
```

Like this:

```
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

        LoadApplication(new App());

        CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener>();
        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Comment: That's not it. I ended up creating a dependency service with a similar implementation to the plugin, and that worked. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to share your implemetation and select it as the answer for your question, interested to see how you went about it using the dependency service?